# Is there a Microdata version of JSON-LD’s "@id"?

Tags: url, html5, microdata

I'm trying to generate Microdata markup (making use of Schema.org). I know that JSON-LD has a `"@id"` which helps reference that whatever data is.

Is there a similar thing for Microdata? As I wouldn't want to copy and paste all the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `itemid` attribute ([W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#attr-itemid), [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#attr-itemid)).

Example:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemid="/team/alice#i">
  <!-- this person (not the page about this person) has the URI "/team/alice#i" -->
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  <link itemprop="author" href="/team/alice#i" />
</div>
```